# Access a VM in the same network as the nodes of my cluster from a pod

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster with some nodes and a VM in the same network as the nodes. I need to execute a command via SSH from one of my Pods in this VM. Is it even possible?

I do not control the cluster or the VM, I just have access to them.

Comment: @Matt That answers the reverse (running a command inside from outside).  This question is asking about running a command outside from inside.

Comment: Do you get an error when you try this?  Pods inside a cluster should be able to access everything outside the cluster (via NAT) just fine.

Comment: @Pace actually, I tried with just a Docker container, not in the cluster. I just assumed that it wouldn't work on kubernetes as well and I wanted a solution for kubernetes. Should it just work? Can I just use the nodes-vm network IP? (It'll take me a while to test it)

Comment: @Matt no, I will run the ssh command from my application when I hit an endpoint (let's not discuss how ugly this is, not my choice :D )

Comment: @andrew Ok, you have an interface to go in to trigger the ssh instead of `exec`.  So the answer to your question is "yes".  The only things that would stop it are local infrastructure setup like firewalls which external people can't really comment on.

Comment: However, I would point out that outgoing connections should be allowed from a docker container as well.  So if you are having trouble in a docker container it seems possible you will have trouble in Kubernetes.  One thing to check with Docker (that kubernetes should manage for you) is to confirm the host machine has IP forwarding enabled: https://docs.docker.com/v1.5/articles/networking/#communication-between-containers-and-the-wider-world

Comment: You may also need to configure IP masquerading and forwarding in iptables.  Again, Kubernetes should manage this for you.  This question may help if you want to try with docker: https://askubuntu.com/questions/227369/how-can-i-set-my-linux-box-as-a-router-to-forward-ip-packets

Comment: FYI:  Just saw this on GCE in case you are using Google for your cloud provider: "Beginning with Kubernetes version 1.9.x, automatic firewall rules have changed such that workloads in your Kubernetes Engine cluster cannot communicate with other Compute Engine VMs that are on the same network, but outside the cluster. This change was made for security reasons.

You can replicate the behavior of older clusters (1.8.x and earlier) by setting a new firewall rule on your cluster."

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a network level issue. When you have a kubernetes cluster onthe same network as your target there is a potential issue that might or might not show up - origin IP on the tcp connection. IF your nodes will MASQ/SNAT all of the outgoing traffic then you are fine, but... for a vm in the same domain as kube nodes it might actually be excluded from that MASQ/SNAT. The reason for that is that kube nodes do know how to route traffic based on POD IP cause they have the overlay networking installed (flannel, calico, weave etc.).

To round this up, you need to either have the traffic to your destination node on MASQ/SNAT at some point, or the target node has to be able to route traffic back to your POD, usualy meaning that it needs overlay networking installed (with the exception of setups that are implemented on higher networking level then nodes them selves, like ie. AWS VPC routing tables)